# I want to crawl a search engine, but the search query is encoded

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup, search-engine

I am now crawling a Chinese search engine. One of the search url is "https://xueshu.glgoo.net/scholar?hl=zh-CN&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%E4%BA%BA%E5%B7%A5%E6%99%BA%E8%83%BD&btnG="

The original page is like this 
[Expected page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpODx.png).
But when I use JSOUP for the crawling, the obtained page is like this[Obtained page with JSOUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCO8F.png).
The crawled page is searching the encoded query term.
Is there any one could solve this problem.

My code is here

```
    url = "https://xueshu.glgoo.net/scholar?lr=&q=%E4%BA%BA%E5%B7%A5%E6%99%BA%E8%83%BD&hl=zh-CN&as_sdt=0,5";
    Connection con = Jsoup.connect(url);
    con.header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");  
    con.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br");  
    con.header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");  
    con.header("Connection", "keep-alive"); 
    con.header("Cookie", "NID=122=makZ0dUnna6lDl4kG2AJrr8rj5MhO6kJgX_72-w1ORUGKKLaNim_mhdivMoIF4WVff7NDzBao6RRJNZUbUb0SttOsRnDEWgAh1KxoexAJ7uvO2AECnUJ_Hvx5klujBF4; GSP=LM=1519620995:S=gK3Jhz58HYNpLN1q; Hm_lvt_be2f71fe16256ff72aa6fdbdf058b9f3=1519620973; Hm_lpvt_be2f71fe16256ff72aa6fdbdf058b9f3=1519621078; xid=e97152b3b65b79d1aaded61fa2f71f09");
    con.header("Host", "xueshu.glgoo.net"); 
    con.header("Referer", "https://xue.glgoo.net/scholar?hl=zh-CN&q=%E4%BA%BA%E5%B7%A5%E6%99%BA%E8%83%BD&btnG=&lr=");
    con.header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
    con.header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36");  
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
```

Comment: In your code you are creating Conneciton object that is never used, i.e. the headers you are setting are not used.

Comment: You should look at the encoding of the url String. According to http specification urls should be in latin 1 encoding, but not the query party. Check with encoded as UTF8: url = "https://xueshu.glgoo.net/scholar?lr=&q=人工智能&hl=zh-CN&as_sdt=0,5";